# Can google-fluentd configured to send logs to external splunk?

Tags: logging, fluentd, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-fluentd for sending GCE logs to stack-driver.

It is possible to tweak configuration of google-fluentd to send logs to splunk?

Answer (score 1):

There is a Fluentd to Splunk plugin so it is possible for your use case. Install the plugin then configure it by removing the sections that are sending logs to Google Cloud Logging and add a section to send logs to Splunk. Here are guides and documentations as added reference. [1][2]

[1] https://github.com/splunk/fluent-plugin-splunk-hec

[2] https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Data/UsetheHTTPEventCollector